# JS table input value to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I want to save the value in table > tbody > tr > td > input as JSON. but I could not. When I use the serializeArray structure, it only pulls 2 data. I want to get id and value but I want all 3

HTML Code: https://gofile.io/d/L8xWF1

I try this

```
var myRows = { myRows: [] };

var $th = $('table th');
$('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr){
    var obj = {}, $tds = $(tr).find('tr');
    $th.each(function(index, th){
        obj[$(th).text()] = $tds.eq(index).text();
    });
    myRows.myRows.push(obj);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myRows));
```

```
 var test= $("#tab").find('input').serializeArray();

   
 console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Label</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tab">
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1053</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="active"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1053" data-label="1053" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Aktiv"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1054</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_category"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1054" data-label="1054" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Kategorie Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1055</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_language"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1055" data-label="1055" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Sprache Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1056</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_page"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1056" data-label="1056" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Seite Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Looks like it's typing error. Please find 'td' instead of 'tr'. $tds = $(tr).find('td');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through `tr` using each loop and then create object and add value in  that object using `key-value` and finally push same to array .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var myRows = [];
//loop through tr
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var obj = {} //create obj
  //add value to it
  obj["id"] = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
  obj["name"] = $(this).find("td:eq(1) input").val();
  obj["label"] = $(this).find("td:eq(2) input").val();
  myRows.push(obj) //push obj to array
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myRows));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Label</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tab">
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1053</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="active"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1053" data-label="1053" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Aktiv"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1054</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_category"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1054" data-label="1054" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Kategorie Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1055</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_language"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1055" data-label="1055" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Sprache Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-phrase">
      <td style="width: 50px;">1056</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="add_page"></td>
      <td style="width: 60%;"><input type="text" name="1056" data-label="1056" data-lang="2" class="form-control input_translation" value="Seite Hinzufügen"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: great everything works very well! .. I have another question, I want to create a loop and print the value of the 1st to the value of the 2nd if the keys are the same in 2 JSON files. how can I do that?
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r4GJNQr6CK/

Comment: Hi , can you elaborate more ? what exactly you need to achieve? what do you mean by `1st to the value of the 2nd ..` ?

Comment: There are 2 JSON structures in this code. 

This is # 1 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d85HtNHWHQ/


This is # 2 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vvc3SWR5mm/

I want to take the value in the "name" key in the 1.JSON file and find the "name" key location in the 2.JSON file and print it instead of the label. Since the IDs are in different places (name = blog_comments
label = Blog Kommentare)

Comment: You mean to say change `{ "id": "1077",  "name": "blog_comments", "label": "" }` to `{"id": "1077", "name": "blog_comments",  "label": "Blog Kommentare"}` ?

Comment: yes it is, but IDs are in the wrong place in both JSON files, so I want to fill the spaces by looking at the 'name' key. Have you reviewed the code? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r4GJNQr6CK/
 how can I do that?

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/stw2orud/) .

Comment: yes everything you said worked. Thank you very, very, very much for your help. you are a great developer 